# Django Admin multiple count issue

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-admin

I have an issue with duplicated call of `count` method from Django Admin. Here is my code.

```
class AdminPaginator(Paginator):
    
    @property
    def count(self):
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT reltuples FROM pg_class WHERE relname = %s", [query.model._meta.db_table])
        count = int(self.cursor.fetchone()[0])
        return count
```

... Code from Admin Model

```
list_per_page = 50
show_full_result_count = False
paginator = AdminPaginator


def get_queryset(self, request):
    """
    Overrides default query to exclude inactive entities.
    """
    qs = super().get_queryset(request)
    active_entities = qs.filter(is_active=False)

    return qs.exclude(id__in=active_entities)
```

Django calls`count` method for 4 times and I don't know why.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: read about Signals https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/signals/

Comment: How it can help in my case?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace @property with @cached_property